# http request forwarding according to the http header in apache

Tags: apache, header

I have an apache server that gets http requests with 3 different headers. Depending on the header, I have to send it to backend servers.

Url : abc.com/check

Headers :

"Content-Type: app1"

"Content-Type: app2"

"Content-Type: app3"

Depending on the above header , the request has to be sent to backend app servers .

server1 : http://server1/s1   if "Content-Type: app1"

server2 : http://server1/s2   if "Content-Type: app2"

server3 : http://server1/s3   if "Content-Type: app3"

Please help me out .

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, probably need a lot more information to be able to answer. What backend servers are you using? what is your cloud provider? why apache and not nginx? why not a load balancer? Is a simple answer once the rest of the info is there

Comment: we are using java microservices as the backend servers. We dont have licensed version of nginx . we were using haproxy but its shutting down when we put heavy load. So thought of using apache. we tested apache and its working fine with the load . We just used proxypass for all the requests without doing a header check and apache is operational . So we want to go with apache.

Comment: Also We dont have a cloud provider, we have our own datacenter.

Comment: fyi .. we are getting the below error when using haproxy on heavy load .ar 16 08:42:43 eny*** kernel: haproxy[3747]: segfault at 7f9ed0b3f081 ip 00000000004117bb sp 00007f9ecf298a00 error 7 in haproxy[400000+1d3000]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out .Below snippet works our requirement. Some enhancements I'm thinking is to allow only POST requests .

```
<VirtualHost abc.com:80>
       ServerName abc.com

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} "app1"
     RewriteRule ^/check http://server1/s1 [P,L]

     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} "app2"
     RewriteRule ^/check http://server1/s2 [P,L]

     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} "app3"
     RewriteRule ^/check http://server1/s3 [P,L]

</VirtualHost>
```